# Can jsonpath-plus move elements to child elements?

Tags: json, jsonpath, jsonpath-plus

What I have:

```
    [
     {"Name": "One",
      "ID": "1",
      "Child": [
        { "ChildName": "Alpha"},
         {"ChildName": "Beta"}
      ]
     },
     {"Name": "Two",
      "ID": "1",
      "Child": [
        { "ChildName": "Gamma"},
         {"ChildName": "Delta"}
      ]
     }
    ]
```

and what I'm looking for:

```
    [
      { "ChildName": "Alpha",
       "ID": "1"},
      { "ChildName": "Beta",
       "ID": "1"},
      { "ChildName": "Gamma",
       "ID": "2"},
      { "ChildName": "Delta",
       "ID": "2"}
    ]
```

Extensive searching  gives 'you cant' or 'here is a JavaScript function'.
But there must be an elegant way to solve this common data handling problem?

Comment: Normally, a json library lets you read (or write) json into actual data structures. You can do normal modifications in the actual data structures, not the json itself, because that's just text. I don't see anything in the docs that makes jsonpath-plus different.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var newObj = [];
data.forEach((item) => {
  item.Child.forEach((ch) => {
    var obj = {};
    obj.ChildName = ch.ChildName;
    obj.ID = item.ID;
    newObj.push(obj);
  });
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(newObj));
```

result

```
[
{"ChildName":"Alpha","ID":"1"},
{"ChildName":"Beta","ID":"1"},
{"ChildName":"Gamma","ID":"2"},
{"ChildName":"Delta","ID":"2"}
]
```